# How can I change the location that python binaries install to when building from source?

Tags: linux, installation, python, opensuse, build

I am using openSUSE Leap 15 and I'm trying to build Python 3.7.2 from source by following [this guide](https://realpython.com/installing-python/#compiling-python-from-source).

In doing so, I've taken these instructions:

1. Download the archive
2. Extract the archive into `/usr/lib64/` as root with

   ```
   # cd /usr/lib64
   # tar xvf /home/george/Downloads/Python-3.7.2.tgz
   ```
3. Run the setup commands as root

   ```
   # cd Python-3.7.2
   # ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install
   # make -j 8
   # make install
   ```

These commands don't give me any errors, but they don't do what I expect them to do either. They're supposed to install the new python binary into `/usr/bin/python3.7`, however, that file is never created. Instead, the files are put in `/usr/local/bin/` as follows:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        9 Mar 31 18:18 python3 -> python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 14655464 Mar 31 18:28 python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 Mar 31 18:18 python3.7-config -> 
python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 14655464 Mar 31 18:28 python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3099 Mar 31 18:29 python3.7m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Mar 31 18:18 python3-config -> python3.7-config
```

**How can I get the binaries to go to `/usr/bin/` instead?**

I tried creating a symlink in `/usr/bin/python3.7` to point to the one in `/usr/local/bin/` but when I run it, I get an error:

```
# python3.7
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 31 2019, 18:10:07) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180323 [gcc-7-branch revision 258812]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/etc/pythonstart", line 7, in <module>
import readline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
>>>
```

Trying to set up a virtual environment on this failed as well.

I considered moving all the python3.7 files that are in `/usr/local/bin/` to `/usr/bin`, but I am concerned because python3.6 is already in there and each version has different other related binary files (like `python3.7m-config`).

Comment: Do you get the same error if you `import readline` in the non-symlinked version. (The one in `/usr/local/bin`)

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing in the non-sym-linked version, module not found.

Comment: You should be able to select the install destination using the `--prefix` option of `configure`. For instance: `./configure --prefix=/usr/bin`. That said, I think that `/usr/bin` is normally only for things installed by the distribution's official packaging system. You may have issues in the future if you do so.